# EPERM error when running npm install global using Git Bash?

Tags: bash, bower

If I use Command Prompt and run it as admin, I get no problems.

But when I use Git Bash, for whatever reason, when I try to install anything globally, I get this error:

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\.staging'...
```

When I'm installing packages locally in specific project folders, a plain `npm install`, it works perfectly. But I've been trying to run `npm install -g bower` successfully to no avail.

Sure, I can just run `cmd` as admin, but I was hoping to get to the bottom of this and understand the problem.

I've tried reinstalling Git Bash, reinstalled Node.js, but still didn't make any progress.

Comment: Have you tried running `git bash` as admin?  Sounds like your (non-admin) user ID doesn't have permission to write to the directory where packages are globally installed

Comment: (by the way, I'm not suggesting running as admin as a solution; people fall back on that *way* too often.  The above is simply for diagnostic purposes, to confirm that's what's wrong.  The solution, if you're supposed to have permissions to do what you're trying to do, is to fix the permissions.)